# Create Azure Resource Policy to enforce user?

Tags: azure, resources, azure-virtual-machine, policy

I am looking for an option to enforce user to use specific image, i am trying to modify below code to use HuB image

. Below is the code I am trying to modify to enforce windows HuB

```
"if": {
  "allOf": [
    {
      "field": "type",
      "in": [ "Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines", "Microsoft.Compute/VirtualMachineScaleSets" ]
    },
    {
      "field": "Microsoft.Compute/licenseType",
      "exists": Windows_Server
    }
  ]
},
"then": {
  "effect": "deny"
}
```

}
}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If my understanding is right, you could firstly find Hub images's SKU.

For Windows Server:

```
PS C:\Program Files\> Get-AzureRmVMImagesku -Location westus -PublisherName MicrosoftWindowsServer -Offer WindowsServer-Hub|select Skus

Skus
----
2008-R2-SP1-HUB
2012-Datacenter-HUB
2012-R2-Datacenter-HUB
2016-Datacenter-HUB
```

For Windows Client:

```
PS C:\Program Files> Get-AzureRMVMImageSku -Location "West US" -Publisher "MicrosoftWindowsServer" -Offer "Windows-HUB"|select Skus

Skus
----
Windows-10-HUB
```

More information about this please refer to this [blog](http://hanusoftware.com/hanu-how-to-building-a-virtual-machine-using-hybrid-use-benefit-in-microsoft-azure/) and this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/hybrid-use-benefit-licensing).

According to the [official document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/policy?toc=%2fazure%2fazure-resource-manager%2ftoc.json#permitted-virtual-machines). Maybe you could modify your policy as below:

```
{
  "if":{
   {
     "anyOf": [
       {
         "field": "Microsoft.Compute/imageSku",
         "like": "2016-Datacenter-HUB*"
       },
       {
         "field": "Microsoft.Compute/imageSku",
         "like": "Windows-10-HUB*"
       },
       {
       .....
       }
     ] 
   }
  },
 "then": {
        "effect": "deny"
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, I was thinking to use "field":"Microsoft.Compute/licenseType",
      "contains": Windows_Server"                                                                                        I believe your approach is much better, thanks again.

Comment: $PolicyAssignmentName = "LimitVMHuBTest"
$RG = Get-AzureRmResourceGroup -Name "AzurePolicyTest"
$Scope = "/subscriptions/$($Sub.Subscription.SubscriptionId)/resourceGroups/$($RG.ResourceGroupName)"   throws an error , hope i have written scope correctly ?

Comment: When i am trying to assign the policy i am getting below error, New-AzureRmPolicyAssignment -Name $PolicyAssignmentName -PolicyDefinition $PolicyDefinition -Scope $Scope
New-AzureRmPolicyAssignment : The pipeline has been stopped.
At line:1 char:1
+ New-AzureRmPolicyAssignment -Name $PolicyAssignmentName -PolicyDefini ...New-AzureRmPolicyAssignment : SubscriptionNotFound : The subscription 'resourceGroups' could not be found.

Comment: @techie Could you ask a new question about this, comments are hard to read.

Comment: Sorry , yes , i will, Thanks walter

Comment: Do you want me to skip the below entries in the Jason file ? its adding confusion  also pls suggest I have used "allOf" instead of "anyOf" hope that's not going to  affect the definition?                                                                                                           "field": "type",
      "in": [ "Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines", "Microsoft.Compute/VirtualMachineScaleSets" ]